# List sort- how to configure routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a view which lists some data. I want to make it sortable. The problem is that with my route configured

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Sort",
            url: "Cars/Index/SortBy/{column}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Cars", action = "Index", column = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I am always getting null parameter in my controller class. I try opening `/Cars/SortBy/columnname` or `/Cars/Index/SortBy/columnname` it doesn't work. Only `/Cars/Index?sortBy=columnname` works

```
    public ActionResult Index(string SortBy)
    {
        switch (SortBy) // SortBy is null
        {
            case "manufactuer":
                return View(db.Cars.OrderBy(c => c.Model.Manufacturer.Name));
                break;

            case "model":
                return View(db.Cars.OrderBy(c => c.Model.Name));
        }

        return View(db.Cars);
    }
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your action method parameter name to `column` as that is what you used in defining the route.

```
public ActionResult Index(string column)
{
  return View();
}
```

Then it will work for the url `Cars/Index/SortBy/model`

If you want it to work for the url `Cars/SortBy/model` (without the Index), You can use this route definition.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Sort",
    url: "Cars/SortBy/{column}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Cars", action = "Index", column = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
// Your other default route definition goes below this
```

Or if you are using Attribute routing,

```
[Route("Cars/SortBy/{column}")]
public ActionResult Index(string column)
{
   return View();
}
```

Make sure to enable attribute routing in your `RegisterRoutes` method for attribute routing to work.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{    
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    //Custom and default route definitions goes here
}
```